# Cascades camera error on Blackberry emulator : ViewFinder starting failed

Tags: c++, qt, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am trying to open a camera in Blackberry Cascades 10.2

```
import bb.cascades.multimedia 1.0
import bb.multimedia 1.0
import bb.cascades 1.2
import bb.system 1.2
Page {
  titleBar: TitleBar {
     title: "QML Camera Sample App"
  }
  content : Camera {
     id: qmlCameraObj
     property bool photoBeingTaken
     onTouch: {
        if (photoBeingTaken == false) {
           photoBeingTaken = true;
           qmlCameraObj.capturePhoto();
        }
     }
     onCameraOpened: {
        qmlCameraObj.startViewfinder();
     }
     onCameraOpenFailed: {
        console.log("camera open failed")
     }
     onViewfinderStarted: {
       photoBeingTaken = false;
     }
     onViewfinderStartFailed: {
        console.log("view finder failed")
     }
     onPhotoCaptureFailed: {
        console.log("Photo capture failed")
        photoBeingTaken = false;
     }
     onPhotoSaveFailed: {
        console.log("Photo save failed")
        photoBeingTaken = false;
     }
     onPhotoSaved: {
        photoBeingTaken = false;
     }
     onCreationCompleted: {
        qmlCameraObj.open(CameraUnit.Front)
    }
  }
}
```

I also add the appropriate libs in the .pro and these line to my bar-descriptor.xml

```
<permission system="true">run_native</permission>
<permission>use_camera</permission>
<permission>access_shared</permission>
```

But when i run this code on the emulator, i got in the console : *view finder failed*.
If anybody has an idea of why the view finder doesn't start, it will be helpful.

**EDIT** : It seems that it was the emulator. I download the Beta 10.2.1 and it works.

Comment: +1, although you have not shared the camera error type from `bb::cascades::multimedia::CameraError::Typeerror`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. It is a APIFailure errorType which indicate that the operation could not be completed. What does it mean?

Comment: Have you tried this code on a real device?

Answer (score 1):

Camera will not open in emulator. Run it in the Device.